# how to get a GET/POST variable with a c++ CGI program?

Tags: html, c++, server, cgi, cgi-bin

my google-fu has failed me, I'm looking for a basic way to get GET/POST data from an html forum page on my server to use in a c++ CGI program using only basic libraries.

(using an apache server, on ubuntu 22.04.1)

here's the code I've tried

the HTML page:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Our Funky HTML Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Content goes here yay.
    <h2>Sign Up </h2>
        <form action="cgi-bin/a.cgi" method="post">  
            <input type="text" name="username" value="SampleName">
            <input type="password" name="Password" value="SampleName"> 
    
            <button type="submit" name="Submit">Text</button>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and here's the c++ code I've tried:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        printf("Content-type:text/plain\n\n");
        printf("hello World2\n");
    
         // attempt to retrieve value of environment variable
         char *value = getenv( "username" ); // Trying to get the username field
         if ( value != 0 ) {
            printf(value);
         } else {
            printf("Environment variable does not exist."); // if it failed I get this message
         }
         printf("\ncomplete\n");
    
    return 0;
    }
```

I get the feeling 'getenv' is not the right thing to use here.. it works for things like "SERVER_NAME" though.

any thoughts?

Comment: `getenv` reads environment variables, not remote web sites. What are you trying to do? Are you confused?

Comment: When I wanted to learn how to write CGI application, I had no problems, whatsoever, locating the canonical reference page for the Common Gateway Interface, on Wikipedia. Can you explain which part of that specification led you to conclude that you need to use `getenv`, in this manner?

Comment: +Jesper Jukl : not really remote website, it's on the same server, just trying to make a website (for now lets say a log in system, but more so than that I want to learn how to do it in c++ rather than php or something) and since I'm sending variables.. in the same environment, I thought I could read them,

+Sam Varshavchick : I'm terrible at understanding technical jargon, so I looked at other tutorials, and I saw getenv used in several areas, and reading up on what it does (getting environment variables) I thought it might work..

Comment: looks like I can use something like char *value = getenv( "QUERY_STRING" ); to get all the variables, and then parse them manually. (and use REQUEST_METHOD to see if it was GET or POST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, 2 different methods, depending if it's a post or get method:

-GET-
html:

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Website title obv</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 Content goes here yay.
 <h2>Sign Up </h2>
 <form action="cgi-bin/a.cgi" method="get">  
    <input type="text" name="username" value="SampleName">
    <input type="password" name="Password" value="SampleName"> 
 
    <button type="submit" name="Submit">Text</button>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and the c++ (script?) to read the get values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     printf("Content-type:text/plain\n\n");
     
     char *value = getenv( "QUERY_STRING" );  // this line gets the data
     if ( value != 0 ) {
        printf(value);
     } else {
        printf("Environment variable does not exist.");
     }
     return 0;
}
```

you have to manually parse the data

-POST-

html:
just change 'get' to 'post'

c++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Content-type:text/plain\n\n");

    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
    
return 0;
}
```

again, you'll have to manually parse the data, but now you have those values to play around with yourself.

have fun!